# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy For Protected Download

Tags: amazon-s3

I would like to write an S3 bucket policy that would restrict public access to all items in the buckets and only allow downloads done using the AWS REST interface with which the Key and Shared Secret is passed. Any examples or help in writing such a policy would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```js
{
  "Id": "Policy1365979145718",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1365979068994",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "CanonicalUser: 79a59df900b949e55d96a1e698fbacedfd6e09d98eacf8f8d5218e7cd47ef2be"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Make a user for just this purpose (give out that user's key) and replace the CanonicalUser ID  with the ID of that user.  Of course you'll always have full access using the AWS account's root key.

Amazon has a [Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) if you want to use it.